# Generate n-ary binary tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

I try to create random trees from this structure:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a
            | Funktion (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Lambda (Tree a)
            deriving (Show)
```

The problem I have is that I don't even know how to generate a tree with the depth of (for example) 2 which only has "Lambda" as nodes. If someone could help me with generating this simple tree (depth 2) I could generate them randomly.
If I implement a function like this:

```
build (Tree a) 0 = Leaf "A"
build (Tree a) n = build (Lambda a) (n-1)
```

It won't work since the function build itself expects a Tree as input. Actually I need trees which have the nodes Lambda or Funktion, but first of all I need to understand how to generate a simple version of this structure.

Comment: No it does not expect a tree as input, since `Tree` is not a constructor here...

Comment: Hmm ... So what would be a better input?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "random"? What role does `build` have in tree generation? What type do you expect it to have? You seem to be missing some basics, like the distinction between a type constructor and a data constructor. Perhaps you should take a step back and read some more introductory material?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "n-ary binary tree". A tree with a branching factor of 2 is a binary tree; a tree with a branching factor of *n* is an n-ary tree.

Comment: I am sorry for describing it wrong. I didn't mean n-ary tree. The result of my code should generate a random tree, given a maximum depth. 
build is a try to generate a tree with only Lambda-Nodes. Because I want to understand how to generate trees. I know how to implement a Tree in my Structure. 
For example: tree = Funktion (Leaf "A") (Lambda (Leaf "A"))

Comment: So I managed how to generate a tree only with Lambda. I have done it with list comprehension:
build 0 = [Leaf]
build n = [Lambda a | a <- build (n-1)]
But how can I randomize this now?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like

```
build :: Natural       -- ^ Number, n, of Lambda nodes
      -> a             -- ^ Value, v, to store in the Leaf
      -> Tree a        -- ^ Lambda^n (Leaf v)
build 0 a = Leaf a
build n a = Lambda (build (n - 1) a)
```

So that `build 4 "A"` will produce

```
Lambda (Lambda (Lambda (Lambda (Leaf "A"))))
```

Unfortunately, the rest of your question (about generating random trees) really requires substantially more context to answer.

Comment: thanks, that was what I was looking for. The problem with the random trees is that I want to generate trees. Which randomly decide wether to place a Lambda (unary node) or a Funktion (binary node)

Comment: @P.Barthel, in Haskell, if you want to make random things, you kind of need some context. *Why* are you trying to make random trees? What are you going to do with them? The answer to *how* may be radically different depending on *why*.

Comment: Some things to look at are `quickcheck`, `tf-random`, and `random-fu`, but it all really depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The actual thing I want to create is something called freshness constraints. It's a topic of the nominal unification. These constraints consist of Lambdas and Functions. I need to create random constraints in which Atoms (thats why the "A" in the Leaf) are bounded by either a Function or a Lambda. But these constraints shouldnt be completely random. They should be limited by a maximum depth.

Comment: @P.Barthel, what the trees *mean* is not relevant here. The question is really more about how you plan to *use* the ones you generate randomly. Are you trying to create test cases? Are you trying to implement a [randomized algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm)? Etc.? Do you need a specific random distribution?

Comment: I have an implemented data structure given which I want to consign the order I got from the trees. A equal possibility distribution is totally fine

Answer (score 0):

You're close - your `build` function at the moment will always return a `Leaf`, as the base case of the recursion doesn't *do* anything with its argument. You don't actually need the argument:

```
build :: Integer -> Tree String
build 0 = Leaf "A"
build n = Lambda $ build (n-1)
```

This would produce what your `build` function seems to be intending, that is a simple "tree" of given depth `n` composed of a `Leaf` node and `Lambda` nodes. Eg:

```
λ> build 2
Lambda (Lambda (Leaf "A"))
```

---

To get your randomly generated tree, you need to look at the [`System.Random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html) module.

For example building on the previous, a tree of random height between a given upper and lower bound:

```
buildRandom :: (Integer, Integer) -> IO (Tree String)
buildRandom bounds = randomRIO bounds >>= return . build
```

This can be extended and modified to produce the behaviour you want (a fully random generated tree), but requires knowledge of monads etc., which might take some extra reading.